# Centering Bootstrap Navbar CSS

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center the listed items (without the image and title) in the center of the nabber, and I've tried every single solution but it just won't move!! Does anyone have the slightest clue how to solve this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add a class "**mx-auto**" with "**navbar-nav**" like => "**navbar-nav mx-auto**".

Line should be like

```
<div class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
```

Instead of

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: Ah you beat me to it!

Comment: :) We all here to help each other. best wishes for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `.mx-auto` to `.navbar-nav` that will center nav items between the brand and right side...

This is because the parent `.navbar-collapse` is `flex` so using x-axis margin auto on its immediate child elements so you can control x-axis positioning using margins.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class **`justify-content-center`** with `collapse navbar-collapse`.

So collapse `div` should have class like:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#horizontal-alignment

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

bro here is the answer that i understand if there is issue tell i help u out as must as i can :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    Hello
  </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav float">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .float{
            margin: auto;
            
        }
```

Comment: No need to create custom `.float` style as bootstrap 4 has [margin utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/) to handle this.